# How to check which version of library is used and how to change?

Tags: shared-library, imagemagick

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed, with ImageMagick and `libjpeg6` and `libjpeg8` libraries installed.

I am now wondering if there is a way to determine, which version of `libjpeg` is used by ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine which library a program is using you can look with `strace`:

```
user@host:~$ strace -e open gimp 2>&1 | grep libjpeg
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

Answer (score 7):

to list all the libraries installed in your system and with their versions you can use

```
ldconfig -v
```

&

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

both will work but 2nd command list all the libraries which need to be have root permissions to list.

to **Filter specific package** , use its name as argument. for example to list all jpeg libraries installed

```
ldconfig -v | grep jpeg
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks... but I know that I have libjpeg 6 and 8 installed, but what I want is to know which one is used by imagemagick, and how to change it ;)

Comment: Well you can't. Because each library there do some particular function. If a new library adding can improve applications functionality then Ubuntu Developers will add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the currently installed version of any package using `apt-cache policy`. The output should look like this:

```
libjpeg8:
  Installed: 8c-2ubuntu8
  Candidate: 8c-2ubuntu8
  Version table:
 *** 8c-2ubuntu8 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

It shows both the installed version as well as all other versions available – just one here. If there's another version, you can install it using `apt-get install <package>=<version>`, if that version does exist, e.g.:

`apt-get install libjpeg8=8c-ubuntu9`

Comment: Ok, thanks... but I know that I have libjpeg 6 and 8 installed, but what I want is to know which one is used by imagemagick, and how to change it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP may have actually had the end goal of checking/updating their version of ImageMagic, you may need to just check which version you're using.  In this case it's as simple as this

```
convert --version
```

will return something like:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```